# Cheap solution to cease creking sound of parquet floor

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, parquet

I have parquet flooring in both of the rooms in my rental (block of flats). The problem is that they are laid down when these houses were built (~40 years ago), and when they did that, they didn't let them dry enough.

Basically it's loud as hell, and it is impossible to walk silently.

Please help me found a cheap solution with these conditions:

- I can't remove or change the floor, just work on it's surface
- I can't screw or nail the wooden pieces to the subfloor

A possible solution is polishing the floor, but it's a little bit difficult for me, and i have to rent machines to do that.

What i'm thinking about is to apply some kind of wax or grout on the floor, or some kind of oil that would rehydrate it, but I can't tell if they would help.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes shaking talcum powder onto the floors and sweeping it into the joint lines will help for a time. It acts as a lubricant to reduce the friction as the boards shift.